# Bootstrap tooltip not working on live site but woking fine on console

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Bootstrap tooltip is woking fine on console but not in live, I am using jquery ui too, jQuery UI version is v1.10.4 and bootstrap version 3.3.6.
Below is the code that I am using:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

This is my js files which I am using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.min.css"/>-->


<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you show an html snippet as well?

Comment: Where's the HTML part where you actually add the element that should have tooltip? You sure you've added `data-type="tooltip"` or `data-toggle="tooltip"` according to what you're using in your HTML?

Comment: use data-toggle instead of data-type..I faced same problem then its worked by changing this only..

Comment: @Sumobob this my html part:
<label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip dummy text." class="t-tip">Some text<a class="why_ask" onclick="quiz._popModal('q307')">[Why Do We Ask]</a></label>

Comment: @chrisv this is my html part:
<label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip dummy text." class="t-tip">Some text<a class="why_ask" onclick="quiz._popModal('q307')">[Why Do We Ask]</a></label>

Comment: Add this to your post! :)

Comment: BTW Which part of that html do you want to show tooltip on? Do you want it to show on `Some text` or on `[Why Do We Ask]` or both?

Comment: @chrisv On some text.

Comment: Check out my answer, and let us know how it goes! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: My html part <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip dummy text." class="t-tip">Some text<a class="why_ask" onclick="quiz._popModal('q307')">[Why Do We Ask]</a></label> I tried $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); but this only works in console not it live site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure from your jQuery selector that you added `data-type` in your element if you want to use it 
 **OR** select with `data-toggle="tooltip"`

Check the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heshamElghndour/dzkCz/50/)** example

Comment: My html part <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip dummy text." class="t-tip">Some text<a class="why_ask" onclick="quiz._popModal('q307')">[Why Do We Ask]</a></label> I tried $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); but this only works in console not it live site.

Comment: I added it on my fiddle example and it works. check it here http://jsfiddle.net/heshamElghndour/dzkCz/51/

Comment: And make sure of your including for jQuery as first then bootstrap.js as the bootstrap.js is just jquery plugin.

Comment: Yes I included jQuery first then bootstrap, but nothing worked, tooltip() only works in console but not in live in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment below OP, you say that you want to the tooltip to show on `Some text` only. Your HTML indicates that you want it to show on the entire label. But anyway: I made you a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Lkg3mag5/2/) where I use jQuery and jQuery UI to show the tooltip on `Some text` only.

Your code snippet in OP indicates the correct order, but ensure jQuery script is added in HTML BEFORE jQuery UI and Bootstrap is! ;)

Shortly explained: Tooltip can't be triggered without an element (i.e. `<p>Some text</p>`. I restructured your HTML attributes in the fiddle, so that the tooltip is triggered on the paragraph.

HTML restructured to suit your comment.

```
<label>
  <p data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip dummy text." class="t-tip">
    Some Text
  </p>
  <a class="why_ask" onclick="quiz._popModal('q307')">
    [Why Do We Ask]
  </a>
</label>
```

JS / jQuery (just reused your code snippet from OP).

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```